# Push record into local store and update template

Tags: ember.js

I'm using `this.store.push` to push a record into the store from with the application controller (this action is being called from a socket service that is initialized in the application controller), using ember `2.2.1` I am achieving this like

```
var newStoreRecord = this.store.push({
    data: {
        id: id,
        type: 'cart',
        attributes: newCartItem
    }
});
```

This adds this new item into the store but the template doesn't update to show the new item, I also tried adding something like this

`this.get('cart.model').pushObject(newStoreRecord);` assuming that I had something like `cart: Ember.inject.controller(),` at the top of the controller, might have had that one wrong anyway.

In the cart route I have my model being defined as so

```
model(params) {
    this.set('routeParams',params.event_url);
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      event: null,
      items: null
    });
},
actions: {
  didTransition() {
     this.store.findRecord('event',this.get('routeParams')).then((result)=>{
        this.controller.set('model.event',result);
     });
     this.controller.set('noItems',false);
     this.store.query('cart',{auction_id:this.get('routeParams'),user:this.get('user.user.user_id'),combine:true}).then((result)=>{
        if(!result.get('length')){
      this.controller.set('noItems',true);
      return null;
        }else{
      this.controller.set('model.items',result);
    }
    });
  },
}
```

Not sure if I'm having troubles with getting the template to update because I'm not use the model hook? (btw, we're not using the model hook because of the bad performance on android we'd rather load an empty template with a loader and THEN load data rather than the other way around.

Comment: Can you add your template code? Also, where are you doing your `push()`? I don't see that either.

Answer (score 1):

I have several thoughts here:

To answer your question specifically, when you set a variable from the store, like you're doing, it will only reference what was in the store *at that time*. It will not update automatically.

Your best bet is to add two new computed properties to your controller:

```
items: Ember.computed(function() {
  return this.store.peekAll('cart');
}),

// You'll need to flesh this one out further
filteredItems: Ember.computed('items.@each.auction_id', function() {
  return this.get('items').filter(...);
})
```

Reference `filteredItems` in your template and it should work.

Sidenote, I'd highly recommend refactoring a couple things.

- I would use the [`setupController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) hook instead of `didTransition`. It runs after the model hook is complete so will be similar to what you're looking for
- You can [access the params](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_paramsFor) at any time in the route, so you don't need to save them in the model hook
- You don't need to return an a promise in the model hook if you're not doing any async data. Just return the object. You may need even need to do that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what am I trying to do here with your code? Is the filteredItems computed just listening for something to change so it knows to get items again? If so I should be able to have that listen to anything that I know will change when I want to load the items again correct?

Comment: Right. `PeekAll` is sort of a live query to the store. So whenever you push to the store, that will update, triggering the `filteredItems` computed property to re-evaluate which will then update your template.